# Azure Mobile Service Query Param

Tags: android, azure

I have more than one read query.

```
Query query = QueryOperations
                    .field("deleted").eq(false)
                    .select("title", "price", "district","anouncement_id")
                    .orderBy("announce_from", QueryOrder.Descending)
                    .skip(countIsLoaded) // counter
                    .top(5);
```

Another one is or ecc..

```
Query query = QueryOperations
                .field("deleted").eq(false)
                .orderBy("created", QueryOrder.Descending)
                .skip(countIsLoaded) // counter
                .top(5);
```

I will have to query using an Andriod Async Task. 
Now i have more than one asyntask because i have not find a method to pass the query for Azure Mobile Service. This is the code currently i have

```
try {
    MobileServiceTable<Foo> mToDoTable = MakeEasyApplication.mClient.getTable(Foo.class);

    MobileServiceList<Foo> listAnnounce = mToDoTable.where()
                 .field("deleted").eq(false)
                 .select("title", "price", "announce_from", "district","anouncement_id")
                 .orderBy("announce_from", QueryOrder.Descending)
                 .skip(countIsLoaded)
                 .top(5)
                 .execute().get();
    for (Foo foo: listAnnounce) {
        publishProgress(foo);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How i can pass the query param instead of having multiple Async Task?

Answer (score 0):

@JoJo, per my experience, I think there are two ways to wrap multiple queries for a async task.

1. Wrap multiple queries with different query name defined into a function.

   ```
   public Query getQuery(String qName) {
       Query query = null;
       switch(qName){
           case "QN1":
               query = QueryOperations
                       .field("deleted").eq(false)
                       .select("title", "price", "district","anouncement_id")
                       .orderBy("announce_from", QueryOrder.Descending)
                       .skip(countIsLoaded) // counter
                       .top(5);
               break;
           case "QN2":
               query = QueryOperations
                   .field("deleted").eq(false)
                   .orderBy("created", QueryOrder.Descending)
                   .skip(countIsLoaded) // counter
                   .top(5);
               break;
           //......
           default: 
           //......
       }
       return query;
   }

   //In async task
   Query query = getQuery("<qName>");
   MobileServiceTable<Foo> mToDoTable = MakeEasyApplication.mClient.getTable(Foo.class);
   MobileServiceList<Foo> listAnnounce = mToDoTable.where().execute(query).get();
   ```
2. Using Custom APIs, you can define a custom API in the Mobile [backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#CustomAPI) and call the custom API in [Android client](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/#custom-api), then using the name of custom API as parameter instead of having multiple async task.

Comment: Woww--------------- Thanks you very much.. superb clear

Comment: `MobileServiceList<Foo> listAnnounce = mToDoTable.where().execute(query).get();` for this method i can not pass query as you have written..